# Утекает память в golang

Tags: golang

Задумал я обкачать интернет. Сделал пару десятков тысяч воркеров. Скачал домены и запустил обход. Течёт память в воркере. Никак не могу найти.

```
func worker(timeout time.Duration, wg *sync.WaitGroup, in chan Pair, out chan Pair) {
  client := &fasthttp.Client{
    MaxIdleConnDuration: timeout,
  }
  for {
    scheme := []string{"http", "https"}
    domain := <-in
    for _, s := range scheme {
      time.Sleep(time.Second)
      t := time.Now()
      host := fmt.Sprintf("%s://%s", s, domain.String)
      req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
      defer fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
      req.Header.SetMethodBytes([]byte("GET"))
      req.SetRequestURI(host)
      resp := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()
      defer fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)
      err := client.DoTimeout(req, resp, timeout)
      s := fmt.Sprint(domain.Index, time.Now().Sub(t), resp.StatusCode(), err)
      out <- Pair{String: s, Index: domain.Index}
    }
  }
  wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: а как Вы решили, что память течет? то что она постоянно увеличивается?

Comment: Я в нюансах golang не разбираюсь, но фраза «пару десятков тысяч воркеров» меня очень сильно смущает независимо от языка...

Comment: Особенно учитывая, что, если я правильно понимаю, fasthttp вычитывает всё тело ответа целиком: хранить в памяти «пару десятков тысяч» ответов размерм в сотни и тысячи килобайт — сомнительная затея...

Comment: @KoVadim да. htop смотрю

Comment: @andreymal я пробовал стандартным net/http -- та же песня.

Comment: @andreymal в памяти не храню. Сразу забываю. Пишу в консоль точнее

Comment: @hedgehogues ну если «пару десятков тысяч воркеров» запущены одновременно, то в момент от отправки запроса до печати в консоль оно всё равно успеет похраниться и пожрать всю память. Правда, net/http кажется всё-таки не вычитывает тело, тогда не знаю...

Comment: @andreymal оно же должно расти до определённого предела, ведь так? Т.е. 1000 воркеров не должно выжирать все 16 Гб, как мне кажется.

Comment: @andreymal нашёл проблему без решения https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32110

Comment: Ну вот, плюс одна причина почему golang плохой язык... Возможно, вот тут под пунктом #4 предлагают обходной костыль https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/gotchas-of-defer-in-go-1-8d070894cb01

Comment: @andreymal вы ерунду говорите. у го есть своя ниша -- и он очень хорош здесь. написание микросервисов для больших нагрузок. А в моём примере нужно просто defer убрать и всё заработает.

Comment: @hedgehogues присутствие языка в какой-то нише не говорит о том, что язык хорош, лучше писать высоконагруженные сервисы на Rust, в котором многих проблем golang не может быть в принципе. Впрочем, это уже флуд не по теме вопроса

Comment: @hedgehogues а про убирание defer напишите ответ, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal а, нет. я не прав. я просто убрал defer. А эти две функции нужно было ещё и в конец перенести. Не работает такое решение. Проблема та же.

Comment: @hedgehogues профилировали ли вы приложение? можно дополнить ответ необходимым количеством кода, чтобы запустить у себя?

Comment: да, defer в теле цикла я и не приметил. Но просто тело выносится в отдельную функцию (что бы defer теперь был в ней) и все, никаких костылей.

А раст... любой язык будет плохим, если его не уметь использовать.

Comment: @KoVadim это всё равно не помогает

Comment: А вы уверены, что воркеров у вас точно ограниченное количество и они не увеличиваются бесконечно? Покажите как вы используете эту функцию. Вот здесь рассказывается про GC в golang. Возможно это будет полезно и вы захотите запускать его принудительно: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/

Comment: @Inventor запускается n воркеров. Рантайм не обещает принудительного запуска GC. Это только рекомендация ему запуститься. 3 человека воспроизвели проблему.

Comment: @hedgehogues не могли бы вы всё-таки показать код запуска этих воркеров? И вы не правы, что рантайм не запускает GC. `runtime.GC()` Запускает сборщик мусора и блокирует поток до тех пор, пока программа не будет завершена